# Create unique identifier that is a recognisable child of a parent identifier

Tags: c#, guid, entity-relationship, uniqueidentifier

In creating a set of elements identified by guids, I have opted to use children that share the first 12 characters (6 bytes) of their id with their parent and sibling element ids.

Eg:

```
Parent Id: df2f5d11-0b66-4407-8cf4-8877b954a273
Child Id: df2f5d11-0b66-349b-8527-1a6a79d2efce
```

I know that lots of models use a similar mechanism for related entities so I'm wondering if there are prescribed best practices or conventions for recognisable unique identifiers.

My implementation looks like this:

```
var childId = new Guid(parentId.ToByteArray().Take(6).Concat(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray().Take(10)).ToArray());
```

-- which strikes me as a bit clumsy if lots of systems use a similar mechanism.

Is there a better/cleaner/simpler way?

Comment: Are you sure that you won't see the same 6 byte prefix on another parent?

Comment: No, clearly it could happen but in this case it isn't a big deal. The convention is just about human readability, the child entities actually reference their parents with the whole parent id.

Comment: @grenade - fair enough, so this is for human-readability rather than attempting to (re-)enforce the parent-child relationship.  Is your concern that you'll end up with the same code all over the place, that it's inefficient, or is something else bothering you with this approach?

Comment: Actually, when I thought about the approach, I was surprised that there wasn't already a constructor on System.Guid that took a parent id. It's just that I doubt that others haven't used a similar approach and was hoping there was a more standardised implementation.

Comment: Why?  Do you not have a ChildTable.ParentId FK field that links the two together already?

Comment: @grenade - the lack of such a constructor does imply that what you're doing is not the norm.  The concept of a parent of a Guid isn't natural - the Guid class is there to generate GUIDs and these don't have parents.  JKs comment is a good one - the parentID field should be all you need.

Answer (score 1):

I think any manipulation of bytes in GUID will result in breaking of either Unique and Global parts.

And if you want this to be human-readable, then make an application, that shows relations between parent and children.

And can I have links to sources saying this is actualy used?